# Prove the annihilator of a quotient module is a 2 sided ideal.

Tags: ring-theory

R is a ring and  is a left ideal of R. 
Since R is a ring, it can also be considered as an R-module, therefore I is a submodule of R and the quotient R/I is an R-module.

I am trying to solve the following question:
Show Ann(R/I) is a 2-sided ideal of R.

I have found a lot of similar questions online that prove Ann(M) is a 2-sided ideal where M is a submodule of an R-module. I was wondering if R/I is considered to be a submodule?

Comment: The fact that the annihilator of *any module* is an ideal in the ring is proven in many places on the site, like in the duplicate I linked. It has nothing to do with submodules, really. Even if someone phrased it in terms of submodules, a module is a submodule of itself, and you would still already have your answer. Perhaps you were thinking of left ideals as submodules of R, and had learned that their left annihilators were ideals...